# Eclipse ECL: How to perform a mouse click while pressing a control key?

Tags: eclipse, rcp, eclipse-rcptt

I am testing components inside a JavaFX canvas inside an Eclipse RCP application and have to simulate a mouse left button click while ctrl (or shift, or ALT ..) is pressed.

Does anybody know how to solve this in ECL?

Answer (score 1):

You have to solve it using commands beginning with mouse- and use their -mask CTRL parameter.

```
mouse-press 299 350 -mask CTRL
mouse-release 299 350 -mask CTRL
```